# Notice: Undefined variable: _files

Tags: php, web, upload

A piece of simple code,but I always get the error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: _files in E:\php5\Mywwwroot\d.php on line 5
```

The source code is like blow:

b.php:

```
<html>
<body>
    <form action="d.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="file">filename:</label>
         <input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> <br />

          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

d.php:

```
<?php

var_dump($_files);

?>
```

I don't know what's worng. I googled, but no answer.

I check the php.ini file:

post_max_size = 8M

How can I do now?

Comment: its $_FILES not $_files

Answer (score 4):

Don't forget that PHP variable names are case sensitive.
Super global variables(like $_FILES) are all uppercase.
Try this:

```
<?php

var_dump($_FILES);

?>
```

Comment: it's not true to say that 'PHP is a case-sensive language' since variable names are case sensitive while function names are not.

Comment: But it's not the 'entire language is case-sensitive'. Variable names - yes, they are.

Answer (score 1):

Superglobal array for FILE handling is

```
var_dump($_FILES);
```